# Typescript - migrating JS code with strict flags

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I'm starting to migrate a large JS codebase into TS.

As recommended in the [Migrating from JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) document, I started by setting the `tsconfig.json` file to `allowJs: true`.

The migration procedure is that whenever I add a new file to the codebase, I add it in TS.

Since I want to be as strict as possible for these new TS files, I've added the different strictness options in the `tsconfig.json` file such as `"noImplicitAny": true, "noImplicitThis": true`.

Thing is, once I do so I get a ton of errors for all of my non-migrated JS files that, of course, lack typings for different arguments and therefore have an implicit `any` type.

What is the suggested workflow in this condition?
As described above, I want to:

- Be as strict as possible for the new TS files I create.
- Run TS standard checks on my JS files, e.g. `unreached code` or `unused variables`.
- Not having the same TS strictness on my JS files as it will simply mean I need to migrate all of my code to TS straightaway, which is not really feasible.

Is it somehow possible with different `tsconfig.json` files for JS and TS files?

What is the best practice here?

**Edit:**

As Matt mentioned in the comment below, I was indeed using the `checkJs: true` flag which is what caused the compiling errors in the JS files.

I understood that even without porting your JS files to TS, you receive "out-of-the-box" type checking even when you use .js files, but that isn't happening for me.

Without the `checkJs` flag, I receive `Unreachable code detected` and `'x' is declared but is never used` warnings, but that seems to be it.
For some reason, I was sure that it will also catch stuff like the following:

```
let num = 12;
num = "aa";
```

But it doesn't depict any warnings (and the intellisense doesn't "know" that `num` is of type `number`).

When reading the [Migrating from JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html) article again (the "Early Benefits" section), I can see that it indeed states that all I get is a very limited typing check support.

So last thing before I close this question - is this somehow configurable or that's it?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting implicit-any errors in your JavaScript files unless you turned on the `checkJs` option (which is off by default) or added a `// @ts-check` comment.  Make sure you didn't do either of those things and if you are still getting errors, please publish a repository that reproduces the problem so I can look.

Comment: Thanks @MattMcCutchen, I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will indeed have to use two `tsconfig.json` files, one with `"noImplicitAny": true` (and any similar options) but not `"checkJs": true` and the other with `"checkJs": true` but not `"noImplicitAny": true`.  It should be straightforward to get your build system to run `tsc` once on each `tsconfig.json` file and show all the errors.  You'll probably want to set `"noEmit": true` in one of the two files.  (If you need help with this, let me know.)

If you are using Visual Studio Code as your IDE, then based on my brief tests, there doesn't seem to be a way to get Visual Studio Code's TypeScript language service (used for error reporting as you edit) to apply different `tsconfig.json` files to your TypeScript and JavaScript source files (unless you can separate the files into two folders with dependencies going in only one direction, which doesn't appear to be your scenario).  So you'll have to pick one of the two configurations as your main configuration and refer to the build output for the errors detected only by the other configuration.  (I can't speak for other IDEs.)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, if I use a strict `tsconfig.json` for all of the .ts files, and then create another `tsconfig.jsfiles.json` that extends the first config file with less-strict compiler options that includes all the `**/*.js` files, why would there be an issue with VS code dependencies?

Comment: If you do that, the VS Code TypeScript language service will only look at `tsconfig.json` and won't report any type errors in your JavaScript files.

Comment: I understand.
Is it possible to add a comment similar to `//@ts-check` only with more parameters to control the strict flags? Something along the lines of `// @ts-check @noImplicitAny=false ...`?

Comment: No, `// @ts-check` is on-off.

Comment: For whoever reaches here in hope that this is somehow possible, [the following github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11051) indicates that currently it is not possible **by design**.